# Signing existing PDF document sometimes causes a corrupt file

Tags: c#, pdf, electronic-signature, itext7

I am writing a demo proof of concept to add electronic signatures to existing PDFs. I am running into one weird problem that I don't get. It seems that adding the signature to some documents works fine while adding one to others does not work and a corrupt file is generated that Adobe Reader can not open.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iText;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using System.IO;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Tls;
using iText.Signatures;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math;
using iText.IO.Image;

namespace LTVSkilrikjaDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string welcomeText = "Welcome to LTVSkilríkjaDemotolid!";
            string pressEnterToTry = "Commands: 's' - sign, 'stop' - stops the programme";
            Console.WriteLine(welcomeText);
            Console.WriteLine(pressEnterToTry);

            // Base directory prepared
            string basedir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            int index = basedir.IndexOf(@"bin\");
            basedir = basedir.Remove(index);

            string readString = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            while(!readString.Equals("stop"))
            {
                if(readString.Equals("c"))
                {
                    string inFile = "Infile2.pdf";
                    string outFile = "Outfile2.pdf";

                    // Open PDF document and decide where to write the new document
                    PdfWorker worker = new PdfWorker();
                    worker.ReadPdf(basedir + "App_Data\\InFiles\\" + inFile, basedir + "App_Data\\OutFiles\\" + outFile);

                    // Start working on certificate
                    X509Store store = new X509Store("My");

                    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

                    Collection<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> xcertificates = new Collection<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>();

                    foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates)
                    {
                        if (mCert.Subject.IndexOf("CN=Róbert") > -1)
                        {
                             xcertificates.Add(Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(mCert));
                        }
                    }

                    Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] certificatesProcessed = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[xcertificates.Count];
                    for(int i = 0; i < xcertificates.Count; i++)
                    {
                        certificatesProcessed[i] = xcertificates[i];
                    }

                    var pk = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(store.Certificates[5].PrivateKey).Private;

                    try
                    {
                        worker.Sign(certificatesProcessed, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CADES, "No apparent raisin!", "Lost in Iceland", null, null, null, 0, true, basedir);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("Error! " + ex.Message + "\n\r" + ex.StackTrace);
                        if(ex.InnerException != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                        }
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;                      
                    }
                }
                else if(!readString.Equals("stop"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Command not understood. Understand only 's' and 'stop'.");
                }

                readString = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        }
    }

    public class PdfWorker
    {
        private PdfDocument _document;
        private string _source;
        private string _dest;

        public void ReadPdf(string source, string dest)
        {
            _source = source;
            _dest = dest;
        }

        public void Sign(Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain, Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.ICipherParameters pk,
            string digestAlgorithm, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard subfilter, string reason, 
            string location, Collection<ICrlClient> crlList, IOcspClient ocspClient, ITSAClient tsaClient,
            int estimatedSize, bool initial, string baseDir)
        {
            File.Copy(_source, _dest, true);
            FileStream f = new FileStream(_dest, FileMode.Append);
            try
            {

                PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(new PdfReader(_source), f, true);
                _document = signer.GetDocument();
                _document.AddNewPage();

                // Work the last page
                Rectangle pageSize = _document.GetLastPage().GetPageSizeWithRotation();
                //PdfWriter w = _document.GetWriter();
                //long currentPos = w.GetCurrentPos();
                float llx = pageSize.GetWidth() - 350 - 20; //pageSize.GetWidth() / 2 - 350 / 2;
                float lly = pageSize.GetHeight() - 50 - 20; // pageSize.GetHeight() / 2 - 150 / 2;
                float urx = 350; //llx + 350;
                float ury = 50; //lly + 150;
                PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();
                appearance.SetPageRect(new Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury));
                appearance.SetReason(reason);
                appearance.SetLocation(location);

                byte[] imagebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(baseDir + "App_Data\\UndirskriftDemo.png");
                // It is not possible to use the path as it contains Icelandic characters 
                // which itext chokes on. We use byte array instead
                ImageData imgData = ImageDataFactory.Create(imagebytes);
                Image img = new Image(imgData);
                img = img.ScaleToFit(350.0f, 50.0f);
                appearance.SetImage(imgData);

                int pageCount = _document.GetNumberOfPages();

                // Creating the appearance
                if(initial == true)
                {
                    signer.SetCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING_AND_ANNOTATIONS);
                }

                appearance.SetPageNumber(pageCount);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 50, 350, 50);
                appearance.SetPageRect(rect).SetPageNumber(pageCount);
                appearance.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION);
                signer.SetFieldName(signer.GetNewSigFieldName());

                // Creating the signature
            IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm);

                signer.SignDetached(pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize, subfilter);

                Console.WriteLine("Signing successful!");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                _document.Close();
                f.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please see the documents here then. Infile1.pdf I can not sign but Infile2.pdf is signed fine. Outfile1.pdf is the corrupt file.
https://app.box.com/s/52jqe8qirl80km6hunxucs00dntx70o5

What causes this? Is there something about the input PDF file or the above programme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your program, more exactly in your `PdfWorker.Sign` method:

```
File.Copy(_source, _dest, true);
FileStream f = new FileStream(_dest, FileMode.Append);
try
{
    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(new PdfReader(_source), f, true);
    ...
```

Here you first copy the file to sign to the destination and then append the `PdfSigner` output to it.

But that `PdfSigner` output is the *complete* signed PDF, i.e. the source plus an additional revision in which the signature is added. Thus, in the destination file you eventually have *two* copies of the source and then some signing additions generated under the assumptions that only one copy of the source precedes.

To fix this problem, simply remove the `File.Copy(_source, _dest, true)` operation and don't open the `FileStream` with `FileMode.Append`.

---

Even after this correction, signing of the OP's sample file "Infile1.PDF" still creates a broken PDF while signing the sample file "Infile2.pdf" now succeeds. The cause is the iText 7.0.0 bug explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39163940/1729265) which (as far as I can see) is fixed in 7.0.1. As the "Infile1.PDF" uses object streams while "Infile2.pdf" does not, only the former file is affected.

Comment: I tried commenting out the line with File.Copy(...) but I still get the same error when I try to open the output file. 

The reason I copied the file is that I thought that the original file would be changed which I did not want. Also I did not want to create a temporary file and then finally the final document as seems is done in one example I came across.

Comment: *but I still get the same error when I try to open the output file.* - Please share that file, too. It may display the same error but for a different reason.

Comment: @rbadi76 ah, one additional thing, don't open the `FileStream` with `FileMode.Append`: you don't want to append the `PdfSigner` output to anything, also not to some old test output by chance still there...

Comment: I changed the FileMode to FileMode.Create. Same result. See the two new files in the folder already shared called Outfile1_nocopy.pdf and  Outfile1_nocopy_create.pdf. Folder: [link](https://app.box.com/s/52jqe8qirl80km6hunxucs00dntx70o5)

Comment: @rbadi76 Ok, the new examples have no duplication of file parts anymore. The remaining issue is the iText 7.0.0 bug explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39163940/1729265), and that makes clear why signing your "Infile 1.PDF" fails fatally while signing "Infile2.pdf" succeeds now.

Comment: That's it! I downloaded the source and added the line you mention in that post, built it and updated the dll in my project and voilá, I get an uncorrupted file. Thank you so much for your help!