# iTextSharp - How to get PDF content for signing and then sign at a later time

Tags: c#, itext

I'm developing a client-server application where clients have to sign PDF documents using their signatures and upload them to the server. The task is complicated by the fact that clients don't have the means to embed signatures into PDFs, they can only read raw bytes and produce the signature in the form of raw bytes.

I'm trying to implement the following workflow:

1. The client uploads the unsigned PDF to the server
2. The server opens the PDF, extracts the bytes that the client needs to sign,  and sends those bytes back
3. The client receives these bytes, signs them using a client certificate and sends the signature to the server
4. The server embeds the received signature into the PDF it received earlier.

I found some code samples of extracting bytes to sign and embedding the signature bytes into the PDF ([this is the main sample I'm using](https://github.com/jr-araujo/DigitalSigner/blob/master/DigitalSignerA3.cs)).

The problem is that this sample performs all the steps in one program, it embeds the signature right after getting the document hash without closing `PdfStamper`. What I need is some way to save the document after adding the signature field and getting `sha.Hash`, and then at some later time (when the server receives the computed signature) open the document and embed the signature value into the PDF.

Can you suggest a way to modify this code so that the steps (2) and (4) can be independent, and not require shared instances of `PdfReader` and `PdfStamper`?

Comment: You might have looked for a better example on the iTextPdf web site. If no one else writes something during the night,I'll get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: @mkl, the examples on the iTextPdf web site are almost identical to the piece of code I mentioned, but they are in Java, and much of the code is plain incomprehensible (using magic numbers like `new Integer(8192 * 2 + 2));` without any comments - what does that mean?)

Comment: @AndreBorges, the meaning of this number is the space to reserve in order to allow filling it with a signature of a maximum of 8192 bytes. The *2 appears because the signature is encoded in hexadecimal so it needs  two characters for every byte. The +2 is added to reserve space for the begin and end characters '<' and '>' before and after the encoded signature.

Comment: @AndreBorges, The lack of comments is due to the fact that those examples are from the eBook and the extra explanations normally found in the comments is in the text instead. I've added a line of comments here and there in my answer, but feel free to ask for additional clarification.

Comment: By the way, in iText 7 the details of signing (including the visibility of numbers like that `8192 * 2 + 2`) have been hidden away, now users are pushed towards solutions like in your own answer here, cf. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38875814/1729265).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out myself. [This piece of code](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itextsharp/tutorial/blob/b45663fae16135239266e1f1eff2a3e266ac75d9/signatures/chapter4/C4_09_DeferredSigning/C4_09_DeferredSigning.cs) pointed me to the right direction.

Turns out the process on the server has to be the following:

- Take the unsigned PDF and add an empty signature field
- Compute the bytes that need to be signed based on the modified content of the file
- Save the modified PDF with an empty signature into a temporary file
- Send the computed bytes to the client
- When the client responds with the signature, open the temporary file and insert the signature into the field created earlier

The relevant server code:

```
public static byte[] GetBytesToSign(string unsignedPdf, string tempPdf, string signatureFieldName)
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(unsignedPdf))
    {
        using (FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(tempPdf))
        {
            PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');
            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
            appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, signatureFieldName);
            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1);
            MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);

            return SHA1Managed.Create().ComputeHash(appearance.GetRangeStream());
        }
    }
}
public static void EmbedSignature(string tempPdf, string signedPdf, string signatureFieldName, byte[] signedBytes)
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(tempPdf))
    {
        using (FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(signedPdf))
        {
            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(signedBytes);
            MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, signatureFieldName, os, external);
        }
    }
}

private class MyExternalSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
{
    private readonly byte[] signedBytes;

    public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] signedBytes)
    {
        this.signedBytes = signedBytes;
    }

    public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
    {
        return signedBytes;
    }

    public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
    {
    }
}
```

**Side note**: what bothers me in all those iText samples is the presence of magic numbers (like `8192` here) without any comments. This makes using this library so much more difficult and annoying than it could be.

Comment: Concerning your side note: *"what bothers me in all those iText samples is the presence of magic numbers (like 8192 here) without any comments."* - The examples you linked are related to the white paper Samuel pointed you towards (probably not part of it, `SignDeferred` had been a pretty late addition ti the signing API), and that white paper explains the nature of the 8192 and situations in which a different number becomes necessary.

Comment: @mkl, I haven't been able to find any decent explanation in this paper. The only mentioning of 8192 is this: `There’s a parameter named 
estimatedSize in  code sample. Up until now, we’ve always passed 0 as its value. In this case, iText will start with a value of 8192 bytes`. And no explanation where that number came from.

Comment: Cf. section 3.5 *Estimating the size of the signature content*, the section from which you quoted: "iText makes an educated guess". Thus, 8 KB is an educated guess for the size of the signature content, nothing god-given, merely based on experience. *Normally, this educated guess creates a hole that is too big. If you look inside the PDF, you’ll see plenty of zeros at the end of the signature bytes. So be it. It’s better to provide too much space, than not enough.*

Answer (score 3):

The answer below was taken from our [white paper](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html) on digital signatures, chapter 4, section 4.3.3 Signing a document on the server using a signature created on the client. Code examples [here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-4)

The desired workflow can be seen as 3 major steps:

1. **Presign:**
   Required: pdf, certificate chain
   Serverside, setup signature infrastructure, extract message digest and send the digest to client as a byte-array
2. **Signing:**
   Required: message digest as byte-array, private key
   Clientside, apply cryptographic algorithms to message digest to generate the signed digest from the hash and send this signature to
           the server
3. **Postsign:** 
   Required: signed digest as byte-array, pdf Serverside
   insert the signed digest into the prepared signature, insert the
   signature into the pdf-document

Code examples, iText5 and C#:

**Presign** (server)

```cs
//hello : 
//location of the pdf on the server
//or
//bytestream variable with teh pdf loaded in
//chain: certificate chain
// we create a reader and a stamper
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(hello);
Stream baos = new MemoryStream();
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader,  baos., '\0');
// we create the signature appearance
PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
sap.Reason = "Test";
sap.Location = "On a server!";
sap.SetVisibleSignature ( new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
sap.Certificate = chain[0];
// we create the signature infrastructure
PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(
PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
dic.Reason = sap.Reason;
dic.Location = sap.Location;
dic.Contact = sap.Contact;
dic.Date = new PdfDate(sap.SignDate);
sap.CryptoDictionary = dic;
Dictionary<PdfName, int> exc = new Dictionary<PdfName, int>();
exc.Add(PdfName.CONTENTS, (int)(8192 * 2 + 2));
sap.PreClose(exc);
PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", false);
//Extract the bytes that need to be signed
Stream data = sap.GetRangeStream();
byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data,"SHA256");
byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash,null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
//Store sgn, hash,sap and baos on the server
//...
//Send sh to client
```

**Signing** (client)

```
// we receive a hash that needs to be signed
Stream istream = response.GetResponseStream();
MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream();
data = new byte[0x100];
while ((read = istream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)) != 0)  
    baos.Write(data, 0, read);  
istream.Close();
byte[] hash = baos.ToArray();

// we load our private key from the key store
Pkcs12Store store = new Pkcs12Store(new FileStream(KEYSTORE, FileMode.Open), PASSWORD);
String alias = "";
// searching for private key
foreach (string al in store.Aliases)
    if (store.IsKeyEntry(al) && store.GetKey(al).Key.IsPrivate) {
        alias = al;
        break;
    }
AsymmetricKeyEntry pk = store.GetKey(alias);

// we sign the hash received from the server
ISigner sig = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA");
sig.Init(true, pk.Key);
sig.BlockUpdate(hash, 0, hash.Length);
data = sig.GenerateSignature();

// we make a connection to the PostSign Servlet
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(POST);
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie,cookies.Split(";".ToCharArray(), 2)[0]);
request.Method = "POST";
// we upload the signed bytes
os = request.GetRequestStream();
os.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
os.Flush();
os.Close();
```

**Postsign** (server)

```
// we read the signed bytes
MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream();
Stream InputStream iStream = req.GetInputStream();
int read;
byte[] data = new byte[256];
while ((read = iStream.read(data, 0, data.Length)) != -1) {
    baos.Write(data, 0, read);
}
// we complete the PDF signing process
sgn.SetExternalDigest(baos.ToArray(), null, "RSA");
byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, cal, null,
null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
byte[] paddedSig = new byte[8192];
paddedSig.
encodedSig.CopyTo(paddedSig, 0);
PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
dic2.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).SetHexWriting(true));
try
{
    sap.close(dic2);
}
catch (DocumentException e)
{
    throw new IOException(e);
}
```

I've omitted most of the client-server communication code and focused on the signing logic. I've also not thoroughly tested these snippets, as I had to convert them from java code and I don't currently have a client-server setup to test them with, so copy and run at your own risk.

Comment: These are the references and code samples I had on my mind, too. On stackoverflow one should include the pivotal facts and code pieces in one's answers, though.

Comment: Right, so this was probably better off as a comment to the question. My bad, still learning Stack's etiquette.

Comment: Working on it, have to go through the examples myself for an unrelated problem anyway :)

Comment: `Store sgn, hash,sap and baos on the server` - this is an awfully clumsy solution. The white paper you are referring to has some pretty nasty code in it. Plus, the samples are very incomplete, which makes them pretty hard to use. I managed to find a much cleaner solution that doesn't involve storing .NET objects in server memory.

Comment: Not going to argue there, some of those example could do with a rewrite or at least some additional comments. Our focus right now is mainly on iText 7 though. I'll keep the remarks on magic numbers and comments in mind when I have to write examples myself