# Get PDF content for signing and then sign at a later time

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm following the following post: [iTextSharp - How to get PDF content for signing and then sign at a later time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473244/itextsharp-how-to-get-pdf-content-for-signing-and-then-sign-at-a-later-time) as a base to get the data from the PDF document, create a temporary file with a blank signature and then return the hash of that temporary file. The hash is sent to the client that has the token locally where it is signed and returned to the signed web application. At that point I convert it into bytes and generate the final signed document.

However, the signed document does not have a valid signature, displaying the message: Error in decoding BER.

1) Code to generate the temporary file, add the blank signature and return the Base64 encoding hash:

```
Public Shared Function GetBytesToSign(ByVal unsignedPdf As String, ByVal tempPdf As String, ByVal signatureFieldName As String) As String
    Using reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(unsignedPdf)
        Using os As FileStream = File.OpenWrite(tempPdf)
            Dim stamper As PdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, vbNullChar)
            Dim appearance As PdfSignatureAppearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance
            appearance.SetVisibleSignature(New Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, signatureFieldName)
            Dim external As IExternalSignatureContainer = New ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1)
            MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192)
            Dim Hash As Byte() = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(appearance.GetRangeStream())
            Dim Base64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(Hash)
            Return Base64
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

2) Client get the Hash na sua máquina local (eu não tenho acesso ao certificado) e retorna o hash assinado

3) I receive the signed hash and convert it to bytes and make the final signed file:

```
Public Shared Sub EmbedSignature(ByVal tempPdf As String, ByVal signedPdf As String, ByVal signatureFieldName As String, ByVal signedBytes As Byte())
    Using reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(tempPdf)
        Using os As FileStream = File.Create(signedPdf)
            Dim external As IExternalSignatureContainer = New MyExternalSignatureContainer(signedBytes)
            MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, signatureFieldName, os, external)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Partial Class MyExternalSignatureContainer
    Implements IExternalSignatureContainer

    Private ReadOnly signedBytes As Byte()

    Public Sub New(ByVal signedBytes As Byte())
        Me.signedBytes = signedBytes
    End Sub

    Public Function Sign(data As Stream) As Byte() Implements IExternalSignatureContainer.Sign
        Return signedBytes
        'Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function

    Public Sub ModifySigningDictionary(signDic As PdfDictionary) Implements IExternalSignatureContainer.ModifySigningDictionary
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub
End Class
```

[SignedPDF](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AiDEY7gs0VzT1eUcEpKLQZq6sei4hA)

---

mkl, thanks for the return

I'm doing several tests, because I really don't know what the correct method to be used in this case, since the material is very wide and also old. So I think I went a bit further, because now the certificate data is displayed, but it is displayed: Invalid signature. The documents were altered or corrupted after the signature was applied.

**New Codes:**

```
  Public Function GetBytesToSignNew(ByVal unsignedPdf As String, ByVal tempPdf As String, ByVal signatureFieldName As String, ByVal certificateChain As Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate()) As Byte()
    ' we create a reader and a stamper
    Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(unsignedPdf)
    Dim baos As FileStream = File.OpenWrite(tempPdf)
    Dim chain = certificateChain
    Dim pdfStamper As PdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, baos, Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(92), Nothing, True)
    Dim sap As PdfSignatureAppearance = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance
    sap.Certificate = certificateChain(0)
    sap.SetVisibleSignature(New iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(36, 720, 160, 780), 1, signatureFieldName)
    'sap.SetVisibleSignature(signatureFieldName);
    sap.SignDate = DateTime.Now
    Dim dic As PdfSignature = New PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED)
    dic.Date = New PdfDate(sap.SignDate)
    dic.Name = CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields(chain(0)).GetField("CN")
    sap.CryptoDictionary = dic
    sap.Certificate = certificateChain(0)
    sap.Acro6Layers = True
    sap.Reason = "test"
    sap.Location = "test"
    Dim external As IExternalSignatureContainer = New ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED)
    MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(sap, external, 8192)
    Dim signatureContainer As PdfPKCS7 = New PdfPKCS7(Nothing, chain, "SHA256", False)
    Dim hash() As Byte = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(sap.GetRangeStream, "SHA256")

    PDFHash.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(hash)

    Session("signatureContainer") = signatureContainer

    Return hash

End Function

 Private Sub Sign21032020(signatureContainer As PdfPKCS7, ByVal certificateChain As Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate(), signedBytes As Byte(), tmpPdf As String, signedPdf As String, signatureFieldName As String) As Byte

    Try
        Using reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(tmpPdf)
            Using outputStream As FileStream = File.OpenWrite(signedPdf)
                Dim external As IExternalSignatureContainer = New MyExternalSignatureContainer(signedBytes, certificateChain, signatureContainer)
                MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, signatureFieldName, outputStream, external)
            End Using
        End Using

        ' Return New Byte()

    Catch ex As Exception
        File.Delete(tmpPdf)
        Console.WriteLine("Error signing file: " + ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

**Generated Code64 hash to client sign:**

FB/lxYEGgc4xBSM+JlDx02sw/xtHF8jMT13tS9ZLf3A=

**Signed hash returned from client:**

DU7koJKqS8/7+O00Te7F/IyZCZrIWlTxaOwAAdJWK2SsZyNAr1fxb4AnoImlQe3xKR680egdG5orJgD4iiU4GdcM0LgIrTO/+yFwz+rAlL6PUsW8ZKi3UkTcnGxGAi3uudGghMv/KnFxknNOVD5JuAvSsL3h6cLjqv8/knb2vfcpm7r5K4ZiyxM7LtvkJ98OwS7D7sErVp6FJTCmijftq6iveF6v5MjPfrzzx43ETKoU1iGrYNiwvR4dgem9gKYibAoQqgpI+Xb6hvDMv0loFYfYhMDgzmIDgSN171ZIdt8FzjIU3vWt5coyhPYYmI23CAX75dED5zQrXZ+IaPD4CQ==

**TempPDF:**

[TempPDF](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AiDEY7gs0VzT1exHGFODW84iOVZwmw?e=Gy9MDw)

**SignedPDF:**

[SignedPDF](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AiDEY7gs0VzT1exI5POPK6uptgHPkA?e=G3EkqV)

**I use this plugin in client to sign the hash:**

[web-pki](https://docs.lacunasoftware.com/en-US/articles/web-pki/get-started.html)

**Thanks again and sorry for the text. I used google translate.**

Roberto Pires

Comment: Please also share a PDF signed by your code.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/b/s!AiDEY7gs0VzT1eUcEpKLQZq6sei4hA

Answer (score 1):

#### Your original code

The main problem here is that you simply took the signature bytes returned by the client and embedded them without further ado into the PDF.

As your signature in its subfilter claims to be a **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** signature, though, you need to embed a PKCS#7 / CMS signature container which is not what your client returns.

#### Your updated code

Here you switched to declare **adbe.pkcs7.detached** in the signature subfilter. This also requires you to embed a PKCS#7 / CMS signature container, and it also is preferable to using **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** which makes use of SHA1, a digest algorithm not considered secure enough anymore, in the context of PDF it even is proven to be insecure.

Furthermore, you now do embed a PKCS#7 / CMS signature container. Thus, Adobe Reader can now decode the embedded signature (no *Error in decoding BER* anymore).

But you build that signature container incorrectly:

- You send the hash of the signed document ranges to your client to sign. This is incorrect. Unless you create extremely primitive CMS containers, the client has to sign a collection of so called "signed attributes" in the container, and the hash of the signed bytes merely is one of those attributes.
- You embed the signature returned by the client both as signature and as document hash in the PKCS#7 container.

So if using the iText `PdfPKCS7` class to create the CMS container, you have to:

- retrieve the signed attributes as byte array using this `PdfPKCS7` method:

  ```
    virtual public byte[] getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(byte[] secondDigest, byte[] ocsp, ICollection<byte[]> crlBytes, CryptoStandard sigtype)
  ```

  (Here the `secondDigest` argument must contain the hash of the PDF range stream.)
- digest that byte array,
- make your client sign this hash,
- set the client's signature bytes in your `PdfPKCS7` object using this method:

  ```
    virtual public void SetExternalDigest(byte[] digest, byte[] RSAdata, String digestEncryptionAlgorithm)
  ```

  (Here `digest` contains the client's signature bytes, `RSAdata` argument must be `null`, and `digestEncryptionAlgorithm` must be "RSA", "DSA", or "ECDSA".)
- finish the CMS signature container using this method of your `PdfPKCS7` object:

  ```
    virtual public byte[] GetEncodedPKCS7(byte[] secondDigest, ITSAClient tsaClient, byte[] ocsp, ICollection<byte[]> crlBytes, CryptoStandard sigtype)
  ```

  (Here `secondDigest`, `ocsp`, `crlBytes`, and `sigtype` must have the same values as in your `getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes` call.)
- and finally embed those bytes into your PDF using `MakeSignature.SignDeferred` with an appropriate `IExternalSignatureContainer` implementation.

Comment: do you any sample for abv method