# Deferred pdf signature with iText and nexU

Tags: c#, .net, itext, digital-signature

I am trying to integrate a client pdf signature in web browser with iText 8 following the European Comission digital signature services implementation (the demo web app can be found here https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/sign-a-pdf, the source code is available here https://github.com/esig/dss-demonstrations/tree/master/dss-demo-webapp).

This implementation uses a desktop signature tool NexU that exposes a rest api to interact with the client certificates. From what I gathered, it does a deferred signature (it prepares the pdf document, sends the hash back to the client which sends it to NexU to sign and then back to the server to add the signature to the pdf file).

The form posts the file to the server and then it follows the NexU flow https://github.com/esig/dss-demonstrations/blob/master/dss-demo-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/thymeleaf/nexu-signature-process.html (client) and https://github.com/esig/dss-demonstrations/blob/master/dss-demo-webapp/src/main/java/eu/europa/esig/dss/web/controller/SignaturePdfController.java (server)

I'm trying to replicate the same flow following using the same process as here [iTextSharp - How to get PDF content for signing and then sign at a later time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473244/itextsharp-how-to-get-pdf-content-for-signing-and-then-sign-at-a-later-time).

```
 public static byte[] GetBytesToSign(List<byte[]> chain)
        {
            using (var reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\sample.pdf"))
            {
                var x509 = new X509Certificate2(chain[0]);
                var cert = new X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(x509.GetRawCertData());

                PdfSigner2 signer = new PdfSigner2(reader, new FileStream("D:\\test.pdf", FileMode.Create), new StampingProperties());
                PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();
                appearance
                        .SetPageRect(new Rectangle(36, 748, 200, 100))
                        .SetPageNumber(1)
                .SetCertificate(new X509CertificateBC(cert));

                signer.SetFieldName("sig");

                /* ExternalBlankSignatureContainer constructor will create the PdfDictionary for the signature
                 * information and will insert the /Filter and /SubFilter values into this dictionary.
                 * It will leave just a blank placeholder for the signature that is to be inserted later.
                 */
                IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite,
                        PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);

                // Sign the document using an external container.
                // 8192 is the size of the empty signature placeholder.
                signer.SignExternalContainer(external, 8192);
                byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(signer.GetNewRangeStream(), "SHA256");
                return hash;
            }
        }

        public static void EmbedSignature(string signatureFieldName, byte[] signedBytes)
        {
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("D:\\test.pdf"))
            {
                using (FileStream os = new FileStream("D:\\test-signed.pdf", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, os, new StampingProperties());

                    
                    IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(signedBytes);

                    // Signs a PDF where space was already reserved. The field must cover the whole document.
                    PdfSigner.SignDeferred(signer.GetDocument(), signatureFieldName, os, external);
                }
            }
        }

        private class MyExternalSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
        {
            private readonly byte[] signedBytes;

            public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] signedBytes)
            {
                this.signedBytes = signedBytes;
            }

            public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
            {
                return signedBytes;
            }

            public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
            {
            }
        }
```

PdfSigner2 is a child of PdfSigner so I could call the protected GetRangeStream() as GetNewRangeStream().

The problem I'm facing is that the generated pdfs don't have valid signatures (Adobe say BER decoding error). Starting to compare from the start, I noticed that the hash I return with GetBytesToSign is very different from the hash that the method getDataToSign from the demo web app returns.

Hash returned by GetBytesToSign **mzxCQT030gx2DAFb+AmU7Vq4F+rFlkm8+AwlBT54mxw=**

Hash returned by getDataToSign **MYH7MBgGCSqGSIb3DQEJAzELBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwLwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMSIEIGqOoVxG7wK2ipK+1GYavLGSy9TI5yRH+fowIKpTm2uSMIGtBgsqhkiG9w0BCRACLzGBnTCBmjCBlzCBlAQgl7+3/3JM2gFd0RDTmxbtLLHqzppW6bvAyt0dJl30XRowcDBgpF4wXDELMAkGA1UEBhMCUk8xFDASBgNVBAoTC0NFUlRTSUdOIFNBMR4wHAYDVQQDExVjZXJ0U0lHTiBRdWFsaWZpZWQgQ0ExFzAVBgNVBGETDlZBVFJPLTE4Mjg4MjUwAgwiDVS0PlmQu/IQU+A=**

Is it possible to return the hash in the same format with iText?

Answer (score 0):

> Hash returned by GetBytesToSign

It is a fixed-size `SHA256` hash

> Hash returned by getDataToSign

It is actually a byte array to be hashed and signed. You need to take a hash of those bytes to get the same output as `GetBytesToSign`