# How can I get ByteRange with iText7?

Tags: itext, itext7

As the picture show , I need to get byte array from ByteRange to do some verify , they are 0 to 840 and 960 to 1200.

[image]

I found the similar question : [In Itext 7, how to get the range stream to sign a pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869300/in-itext-7-how-to-get-the-range-stream-to-sign-a-pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iText in its own verification code needs to do the same thing. It does so in its `SignatureUtil` class. Thus, one can simply borrow from that code, e.g. like this:

```
try (   PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(SOURCE_PDF);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);) {
    SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);
    for (String name : signatureUtil.getSignatureNames()) {
        PdfSignature signature = signatureUtil.getSignature(name);
        PdfArray b = signature.getByteRange();
        RandomAccessFileOrArray rf = pdfReader.getSafeFile();
        try (   InputStream rg = new RASInputStream(new RandomAccessSourceFactory().createRanged(rf.createSourceView(), SignatureUtil.asLongArray(b)));
                OutputStream result = TARGET_STREAM_FOR_name_BYTES) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            int rd;
            while ((rd = rg.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                result.write(buf, 0, rd);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*([RetrieveSignedRanges](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/RetrieveSignedRanges.java#L42) test `testExtractSignedBytes`)*

If you want the byte range as a `byte[]` in memory, you can use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` as `TARGET_STREAM_FOR_name_BYTES` and retrieve the resulting byte array from it.

Comment: Thank you very mush ! That's what I real need !